# C writing Linked List into file

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write linked list to file. I have a problem when adding new element. 
Main problem is when assigning struct (read from file) to `new_node->next_node`, only pointer saved into `new_node->next_node`. 
After i read from the file, try to print then first struct value was printed well and then second value (`node_trx->next_node`) was printed wrong. I need to store values not pointer to `node_trx->next_node`.
So is there anyone who can tell what did i wrong?

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char amount[12];
    int currency;
    struct node_trx * next_node;
} node_trx;
```

Here is add new element code:

```
 node_trx * trx_list;
 if (3 != read_last_trx_from_file(EMVP_LAST_TRANSACTION_OBJECT, &trx_list, &data_set_len)) {
    if (NULL == (f = fopen(tools_get_full_filename_const(EMVP_LAST_TRANSACTION_OBJECT), "w+"))) {
        log_ntrx_error(-1, "Cannot open ticket data set file: %s.",
                strerror(errno));
    } else {
        node_trx * new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_trx));

        strcpy(new_node->amount, disp_amount);

        new_node->currency = currency_code;

        memcpy(&new_node->next_node, &trx_list, sizeof trx_list);

        if (1 != fwrite(new_node, data_set_len + sizeof(node_trx), 1, f)) {
            //error
        }

        free(new_node);
        free(trx_list);
        fclose(f);
    }
} else {
    // Saving first element
    if (NULL == (f = fopen(tools_get_full_filename_const(EMVP_LAST_TRANSACTION_OBJECT), "w")))
    {
        log_ntrx_error(-1, "Cannot open ticket data set file: %s.",
                strerror(errno));
    } else {
        trx_list = BKS_XCALLOC(1, sizeof(node_trx));

        strcpy(trx_list->amount, disp_amount);

        trx_list->currency = currency_code;
        trx_list->next_node = NULL;

        if (1 != fwrite(trx_list, sizeof(node_trx), 1, f)) {

        }

        fclose(f);
    }
```

Here is file reading function:

```
int read_last_trx_from_file (const char * file_name, node_trx * * trx, unsigned * trx_len)
{
    FILE * f;
    *trx = NULL;

    if (NULL == (f = fopen(tools_get_full_filename_const(file_name), "rb")))
    {

    }

    size_t fsize;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(f);
    fprintf(stdout, "file size: %zd\n", fsize);
    if (!fsize)
    {
        return 3; // No data
    } else {
        if (fsize == 1) {
            return 3; // No data
        }
    }

    rewind(f);
    if (NULL != (*trx = (node_trx *) BKS_XCALLOC(1, fsize)))
    {
        if (1 != fread(*trx, fsize, 1, f))
        {
            fclose(f);
            return 2;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    *trx_len = fsize;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my printing data from file code:

```
 node_trx * card_data;
 if (3 != read_last_trx_from_file(LAST_TRX_OBJECT, &card_data, &data_set_len)) {
 while (card_data->next_node != NULL) {
     strcpy(amount, card_data->amount);
     printf("%s AMOUNT \n", amount);
     printf("%d CURRENCY \n", card_data->currency);
     card_data = card_data->next_node;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't usefully store pointers in a file — there's no guarantee that they'll point to the same place when you read them back in.  Therefore, you end up storing only the data, not the links, which isn't all that exciting.  Alternatively, when reading the data back, you have to ignore the pointers and overwrite any value you read with whatever works in the reading application.  You probably follow the list in sequence when writing each node, so the linear order in the file is the order when you read it back.

Comment: Ty for response. How do i store values to next_node, not pointer?

Comment: You know that the next entry read will be the next one in the list.  Do you have access to functions that tell you the file size?  (You can use `ftell()` and `fseek()`, but it is clunky compared with the o/s specific functions.) If you know the size of the file, you can tell how many nodes to allocate, and create an array with `malloc()` or similar, and then read the data into each. The last entry will end with a null pointer. You can decide whether you store the link or not. It's 'wasted' disk space, but people don't care as much about that these days as they did when big drives were 100 MiB.

Comment: (Note that freeing the array requires a single `free()`; trying to free single links will crash your program.)  If you don't know the size of the file, you can allocate a new node for each entry, then read the data.  If there was no data to read, you can delete the node and patch the pointer in the previous node to NULL.  You needed to keep a pointer to the previous node to hook the new one into the list.

Comment: There is.no `struct node_trx` defined in your code. `node_trx` and `struct node_trx` are two different, unrelated things.

Comment: You write a.linked list to a fike exactly the same way you write it to the screen for the user to see, and you read a linked list from a file exactly the same way you let the user input it from the keyboard. If you can show a.list, and you can add a node to the end interactively, you can use a disk file to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the linked list is sequential, you could just store the elements in order they occur.